# Django deployed on Openshift error 500

Tags: python, django, openshift

I was following this Django deploying on Openshift tutorial https://github.com/rancavil/django-openshift-quickstart/wiki/Tutorial-How-create-an-application-with-Django-1.6-on-Openshift

However, I am getting the 500 Server erorr. Here is my code:

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.shortcuts import render
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import namedtuple
import requests

def results(request):
    final_data = []
    url ="http://www.15min.lt/cempionatas/futbolas/pasaulio-futbolo-cempionatas-2014?from=fifa-menu"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    tables = soup.find_all('table')
    for table in tables:
        row = table.find_all('tr')
        data = [[td.text.strip().encode("utf-8") for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in row]
        final_data += data
    group1 = final_data[:7]
    group2 = final_data[7:14]
    group3 = final_data[14:21]
    group4 = final_data[21:28]
    group5 = final_data[28:35]
    group6 = final_data[35:42]
    group7 = final_data[42:49]
    group8 = final_data[49:56]
    return render(request, 'results.html', {"group1": group1, "group2": group2, "group3": group3, "group4": group4, "group5": group5,
    "group6": group6, "group7": group7, "group8": group8 })

def news(request):
    Link = namedtuple('Link', ['title', 'url'], verbose=True)
    links = []
    url ="http://www.15min.lt/naujienos/sportas/fifa-2014/"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    titles = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "vl-article-title"})
    for i in titles:
        links.append(Link(i.find("h3").find("span").find("a").text, url=i.find("h3").find("span").find("a")["href"]))   
    return render(request, 'News.html', {"links": links})

def tables(request):
    Datas = namedtuple('Datas', 'string url', verbose=True)
    url ="http://www.uefa.com/worldcup/season=2014/standings/"
    final_data = []
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    tables = soup.find_all('table')
    for table in tables:
        row = table.find_all('tr')
        data = [[td.text.strip().encode("utf-8") for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in row]
        head = [[th.text.strip().encode("utf-8") for th in tr.findAll("th")] for tr in row]
        for i in data:
                if i:
            if i[1] == "Netherlands": i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/ned.png"))
            elif i[1] == "Cameroon": i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/cmr.png"))
            elif i[1] == "Spain": i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/esp.png"))
            elif i[1] == "Côte d'Ivoire": i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/civ.png"))
            elif i[1] == "Japan": i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/jpn.png"))
            elif i[1] == "Costa Rica": i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/crc.png"))
            elif i[1] == "Switzerland": i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/sui.png"))
            elif i[1] == "Bosnia and Herzegovina": i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/bih.png"))
            elif i[1] == "Iran": i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/irn.png"))
            elif i[1] == "Nigeria": i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/nga.png"))
            else:
                flag = i[1][:3] + ".png"
                    i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/" + flag))
        final_data += data
        group1 = final_data[:5]
        group2 = final_data[5:10]
        group3 = final_data[10:15]
        group4 = final_data[15:20]
        group5 = final_data[20:25]
        group6 = final_data[25:30]
        group7 = final_data[30:35]
        group8 = final_data[35:40]

    return render(request, 'Groups.html', {"group1": group1, "group2": group2, "group3": group3, "group4": group4, "group5": group5,
    "group6": group6, "group7": group7, "group8": group8 })
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^tvarkarastis/', 'polls.views.results', name='results'),
    url(r'^lenteles/', 'polls.views.tables', name='results'),
    url(r'^naujienos/', 'polls.views.news', name='naujienos'),
)
```

On localhost everything is working fine, but on server something goes wrong. Where is mistake? If you need any more info just say.

UPDATE:

Debug part of settings.py:

```
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get('DEBUG', False))
    if DEBUG:
        print("WARNING: The DEBUG environment is set to True.")
else:
    DEBUG = True
```

Update(2):

I am using virtualenv and I have installed in it beautifulsoup4 and other libraries. Here is my requirements.txt content:

```
Django==1.6
YourAppName==1.0
argparse==1.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
requests==2.3.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Despite that, I am getting this error:

```
No module named bs4
```

Comment: Please change `DEBUG=TRUE` in your settings.py.

Comment: Why? Shouldn't it be False in when deploying?

Comment: How can we tell you what is wrong if we don't see what happened?

Comment: It's just give me 500 server erorr. Here: http://mysite-irmantas.rhcloud.com/naujienos

Comment: Mate please switch your debug option ...

Comment: I updated my question with my code from settings.py , mate.

Comment: Please set DEBUG to TRUE if ON_OPENSHIFT and then past the error.

Comment: I have updated my question with additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting an `ImportError` exception, assuming you have all requirements installed, it can be a virtualenv problem. You should manually activate it when running on Openshift. Basically, the `wsgi.py` in the root directory may contain something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

virtenv = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'], 'virtenv')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin', 'activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass

from yourproject.wsgi import application
```

Answer (score 2):

You may check two more things:

First, what about your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting in `settings.py`? When you're on production (what means `DEBUG` set to `FALSE`) you need to set it correctly, otherwise you'll get `HTTP 500` for every request. [See Django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

The second thing is in order to easily install the correct libraries and packages in your production environment you should edit your `setup.py` like mentioned in the tutorial. Your error message tells that there is at least one module missing.

There is already a full example at your [tutorial](https://github.com/rancavil/django-openshift-quickstart/wiki/Tutorial-How-create-an-application-with-Django-1.6-on-Openshift):

```
# Put here required packages
packages = ['Django<=1.6',]

# This is if you like use redis cloud w/Django...
if 'REDISCLOUD_URL' in os.environ and 'REDISCLOUD_PORT' in os.environ and 
   'REDISCLOUD_PASSWORD' in os.environ:
     packages.append('django-redis-cache')
     packages.append('hiredis')

setup(name='YourAppName',          # <= Put your application name, in this case 'mysite'
      version='1.0',
      description='OpenShift App', # <= Put your description if you want
      author='Your Name',          # <= Your name!!!!
      author_email='example@example.com',
      url='https://pypi.python.org/pypi',
      install_requires=packages,
)
```

And it will be processed like this after pushing to your openshift repo:

> When we make the push, all task are execute automatically for install and configure Django on Openshift. This executes $ python setup.py install on the remote Openshift for us.
>
> Basically the tasks sequence are:
>
> 1. Install Django 1.6 and all packages in install_require of the setup.py file.
> 2. Execute the script deploy (file located in mysite/.openshift/action_hook)
> 3. And execute the python script secure_db.py (file located in mysite/.openshift/action_hook) to create the password for the admin user.

Hope this helps!